# What can be the best option(npm package or redis) for caching the response of mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, redis

I have project with requirements that you have to fire the same query multiple time,caching only on demand (not at the time of server started.

Comment: Need more context. When you say run the same query multiple times, would the result vary between every call? If yes, then caching the entire result wouldn't provide the correct result every time when the query is fired. In such cases, you can just get the IDs from MongoDB and pull values from cached keyed with the ID.

Comment: result would not vary on every call.

Comment: Then you can cache the result. But how long would the results not change? Forever? Please provide an example of your use case. Without any concrete example it would be difficult to tell whether the solution will work for your use case.

Comment: result will not change within a week.

Comment: How would we know when the result changes so that we know that looking up from cache would be incorrect? Also, regarding your question on best option - npm package or Redis, you're trying to compare npm's library with Redis. The comparison is not correct. npm packages provide libraries while Redis is an in-memory cache. Please provide details on the scenario and your findings (or proposed solution).

Comment: I have checked npm packages like memory-cache,cachegoose,lru,redis and many more.I am bit confuse in choosing the best one for my project.In my project at a time I need to cache around 100kb,so for 20 app , I need to cache 2mb approx at a time.And requirements are caching be on demand like lazy loading not at the time of server started.And I need to fire the same query multiple time whose data changes within a week or more than that. So I need a simple caching pattern and strategy.I can choose the redis which is most popular one but if I have some simpler option ,then i will opt that one.

Comment: If your caching requirement is just 2 MB, then you don't need an external cache server like Redis. You can cache the values in memory in your server as the size is small. Btw, what do you mean by 20 app? Your requirements are not clear in the question.